# select option width auto increases

Tags: html, css

```
.option100{
    width:100px !important;
} 

<select id="fieldOfInterestSelect" name="fieldOfInterest" class="form-control" required="">
  <option value="-1">SELECT ONE</option>
  <option value="4893" class="option100">Actual(R)rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr</option>
  <option value="4891" class="option100">Customerrrrrrrrrrrrrr</option>
  <option value="4892" class="option100">Daterrrrrrr</option>
  <option value="4894" class="option100">Forecast(R)RRRRRR</option>
</select>
```

My concern is , if the length of text in option is larger than its container's length (`option`), then it should be automatically converted (fit) into multiple lines to fit the container's width.

Comment: That doesn't happen. You can limit the `width` of your `SELECT` tag and that gets applied to the `options` but you can't style your option tag or make it multiLine, but if the `option value` is longer, then it will take the max available space to show Value. `SELECT` is rendered by the operating system not by the `browser`

Comment: can you explain your problem bit more and formate your code?

Comment: @HirenMangukiya he wants to limit the `option` tag `width` so long text value goes multiline instead of going straight out.

Comment: Try to set max-width for your option

Comment: check @hirenmangukiya's solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your answere is here check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zLb1kahj/), use `selectBoxIt plugin` for it.

And let me know it will helps you or not!

Answer (score 1):

This may not be what you want, but you can get two lines per option, by using the "optgroup" tag

```html
<select>
  <optgroup label="Option 1">
    <option value="yes">Option 1 new Line</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Option 2">
    <option value="no">Option 2 new line</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

You can find more details about this topic from this link
[enter link description here](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html-markup-20110113/option.html)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot break a select option. Instead you could provide a tooltip to the options to show lengthy options.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style>
        .option100 {
            width: 100px !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <select id="fieldOfInterestSelect" name="fieldOfInterest" class="form-control option100" required="">
        <option value="-1">SELECT ONE</option>
        <option title="This is my lengthy explanation of what this selection really means, so since you only see 1 on the drop down list you really know that you're opting to elect me as King of Willywarts!  Always be sure to read the fine print!" value="4893" class="option100">Actual(R)rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr</option>
        <option  title="This is my lengthy explanation of what this selection really means, so since you only see 1 on the drop down list you really know that you're opting to elect me as King of Willywarts!  Always be sure to read the fine print!"  value="4891" class="option100">Customerrrrrrrrrrrrrr</option>
        <option  title="This is my lengthy explanation of what this selection really means, so since you only see 1 on the drop down list you really know that you're opting to elect me as King of Willywarts!  Always be sure to read the fine print!"  value="4892" class="option100">Daterrrrrrr</option>
        <option  title="This is my lengthy explanation of what this selection really means, so since you only see 1 on the drop down list you really know that you're opting to elect me as King of Willywarts!  Always be sure to read the fine print!"  value="4894" class="option100">Forecast(R)RRRRRR</option>
    </select>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: No. This is not expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code

Html

```
<select id="resizing_select" name="fieldOfInterest" class="form-control" required="">
    <option value="-1">SELECT ONE</option>
    <option value="4893" class="option100">Actual(R)rrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr</option>
    <option value="4891" class="option100">Customerrrrrrrrrrrrrr</option>
    <option value="4892" class="option100">Daterrrrrrr</option>
    <option value="4894" class="option100">Forecast(R)RRRRRR</option>
</select>
<select id="width_tmp_select">
  <option id="width_tmp_option"></option>
</select>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#resizing_select').change(function(){
    $("#width_tmp_option").html($('#resizing_select option:selected').text());
    $(this).width($("#width_tmp_select").width()); 
 });
});
```

CSS

```
#resizing_select {
 width: 107px;
} 

#width_tmp_select{
 display : none;
}
```

Here is the working jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/FSsG8/623/

I think it should helps you,.